# Npm install not working, after updating node js

Tags: reactjs, npm

Error message screenshots

[1. Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04ibM.png)

[2.Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrEjP.png)

[3.Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MjLj.png)

[Version of nodejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQOdY.png)

Comment: Do not post your error messages as screenshots, just copy-and-paste them into a code block.

Comment: Photo 2 says you haven't install visual studio. It might be a requirement for the project you are trying to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshots, you are attempting to install [the `node-sass` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).

It's deprecated and, as you can see, depends on a binary module that needs to be compiled separately on Windows using the Visual Studio toolchain.

You have two options:

- follow [the instructions in the readme](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/README.md#install) to also install [the node-gyp prerequisites](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)
- switch your project to use the [`sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) module (recommended).

Comment: Not only Node-sass, I can't download other libraries either

Comment: Thanks for recommend sass module working a good